# HyperSQL Database (HSQDLB) - attach a CSV table to stdout?

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, hsqldb, hypersql

HSQLDB can write tables to CSV files, which I heavily use in [CsvCruncher](https://github.com/OndraZizka/csv-cruncher/).

However, when I [tried to point HSQLDB to `/dev/stdout`](https://github.com/OndraZizka/csv-cruncher/issues/41) as a target for the CSV table, it turned out that it's more than a simple dump - it does seeks.

```
  DB error: SQLException bad TEXT table source file - line number: 0 org.hsqldb.HsqlException: file input/output error openning file: /dev/pts/3 error: java.io.IOException: Illegal seek in statement [SET TABLE "te_out" SOURCE '/dev/pts/3;encoding=UTF-8;cache_rows=50000;cache_size=10240000;ignore_first=true;fs=,;qc=\quote' ]
```

Is it possible to make HSQLDB dump a table to CSV using the `SET TABLE ... SOURCE`? Perhaps using some write-only flag, or such?

*Note: I am not looking for a CSV export, as that would mean first creating the table, and then exporting it, which is a performance drawback.*

Comment: Recent versions of HSQLDB support EXPORT and IMPORT of a table as CVS files: http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_data_management_statements If the database is all in-memory (URL example jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test) it can be very fast.

Comment: Ok, I will try, for the output table, to use in-memory, and export afterwards, rather than writing it to a CSV-file-attached table.
Either way: Can that write to stdout?

Comment: It is not possible to write the CSV to an output stream such as stdout.